# Substitute Sr with Mg in MgO

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, crystallography

Could someone please help me with the following question.

Due to the perspective of voids in the MgO structure, what is the maximal amount of Sr that can substitute with Mg. 
And why is it unlikely that it will happen?

Since the quota between the radiis is 0.84 and the size of the octahedral void is 0.414 the atom should substitute all of the Mg atoms. But is it unlikely because of the size of the Sr ion or is it some other factors involved?